# Facebook like on appli

Tags: php, facebook, button, facebook-like

I created a little application in Facebook.

But the script that may proceed to check if People LIKE or not the page is not working ...

I have a section just for fans and another one just for non fans ...
So when I click on the LIKE button, I assume it would put into the FAN part .. but it doesnt ...

Please see the code :

```
require 'src/facebook.php';

$app_id = "appID";
$app_secret = "appSecret";

$loginNextPage = 'http://www.facebook.com/BenefitCosmeticsFrance'.'?sk=app_'.$app_id;

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];


if ($like_status) {
// FOR FANS
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
        'canvas'    => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'next' => $loginNextPage
        /*'req_perms' =>     'publish_stream,photo_upload,user_photos,user_photo_video_tags'            */
        )
);

$fbme = null;

if (!$session) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = ".$loginUrl.";    </script>";  
    exit;   
}
else {

    try {
        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $vars = "access_token=$access_token&pathToServer=$pathToServer&appName=$appName";
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = ".$loginUrl.";</script>";
        exit;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">    
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
</head>
 <body>
 <h1>You Liked The Page</h1>
 <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?    href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FBenefitCosmeticsFrance&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=150&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35&amp;appId=112625882216036" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}   
}
else {
// FOR NON FANS 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">   
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>You Don't Like the Page</h1>
  <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FBenefitCosmeticsFrance&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=150&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35&amp;appId=112625882216036" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
<?php

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

> ```
> <?php
> require 'facebook.php';
>
> $facebook = new Facebook(array(
>
>   'appId'  => 'YOUR APP ID',
>   'secret' => 'YOUR APP SECRET',
>   'cookie' => true,
> ));
>
>
>
>
> $session = $facebook->getSession();
>
> $me = null;
>
> if ($session) {
>   try {
>     $uid = $facebook->getUser();
>     $me = $facebook->api('/me');
>   } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
>     error_log($e);
>   }
> }
>
>
> $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
>
>
> function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
>   list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
>
>   // decode the data
>   $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
>   $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);
>
>   if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
>     error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
>     return null;
>   }
>
>   // check sig
>   $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
>   if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
>     error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
>     return null;
>   }
>
>   return $data;
> }
>
> function base64_url_decode($input) {
>   return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
> }
>
> $data = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST["signed_request"], "YOUR APP SECRET");
>
>
> ?>
>
>
>
>
> <? if ($data['page']['liked']){ ?>
>
> //FOR FANS
>
> <? }else{ ?>
>
> //FOR NON FANS
>
> <? } ?>
> ```